# How to use pipes with ngModel and owldatetime in Angular 8?

Tags: pipe, angular8, ngmodel

I have a date field as below, and I want to use a specific date pattern for this field -

```
<div class="floating-label-wrap">
  <input [(ngModel)]="sourceDatetimeFromDate" [owlDateTime]="sourceDatetimeFromDt"/>
  <label>
    <span class="content-name">Date Range From</span>
  </label>
  <span class="date-trigger-icon" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="sourceDatetimeFromDt">
      <mat-icon>date_range</mat-icon>
  </span>
  <owl-date-time #sourceDatetimeFromDt></owl-date-time>
</div>
```

I have tried the below, but it doesn't work -

```
<div class="floating-label-wrap">
  <input [ngModel]="sourceDatetimeFromDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'"
         (ngModelChange)="sourceDatetimeFromDate=$event" 
         [owlDateTime]="sourceDatetimeFromDt"/>
  <label>
    <span class="content-name">Date Range From</span>
  </label>
  <span class="date-trigger-icon" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="sourceDatetimeFromDt">
      <mat-icon>date_range</mat-icon>
  </span>
  <owl-date-time #sourceDatetimeFromDt></owl-date-time>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done a minor tweak - by having a hidden field for two-way binding, and a visible field with the date pipe.

```
<div class="floating-label-wrap">
  <input aria-label="source date time from" [(ngModel)]="sourceDatetimeFromDate"
    [owlDateTime]="sourceDatetimeFromDt" hidden />
  <input [value]="sourceDatetimeFromDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'" />
  <label class="label-datetime">
     <span class="content-name">Date Range From</span>
  </label>
  <span class="date-trigger-icon" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="sourceDatetimeFromDt">
     <mat-icon>date_range</mat-icon>
  </span>
  <owl-date-time #sourceDatetimeFromDt></owl-date-time>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, just adding the 'value' attribute with the date pipe also works.

```
<div class="floating-label-wrap">
  <input aria-label="source date time from" [(ngModel)]="sourceDatetimeFromDate"
    [owlDateTime]="sourceDatetimeFromDt" 
    [value]="sourceDatetimeFromDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'"/>
  <label class="label-datetime">
     <span class="content-name">Date Range From</span>
  </label>
  <span class="date-trigger-icon" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="sourceDatetimeFromDt">
     <mat-icon>date_range</mat-icon>
  </span>
  <owl-date-time #sourceDatetimeFromDt></owl-date-time>
</div>
```